# Using a json file to populate a <select> tag using ajax and php request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to populate a select tag (id=country-dropdown) with a list of countries which are in a separate file(countryBorders.geo.json)through an Ajax Request in my javascript file (script.js) to my php file (requests.php).

My Ajax Request keeps failing, I've tried lots of different success functions but am unsure what to change. Any help would be really appreciated!!!

**My Ajax Request is now working - the link to my php file was not correct. But I am now not returning the correct data from countryBorders.geo.json. How do I access the name key's value in the twice nested array?**

countryBorders.geo.json - I need to access the value of the name key to show as an option in my select list and of the iso_a2 key to be the option value:

```
{   "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[{"type":"Feature",
                 "properties":{"name":"Bahamas","iso_a2":"BS"} 
etc
```

requests.php - I need to access the above file and return the data to the ajax request:

```
<?php
$url = 'js/countryBorders.geo.json';
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $decode = json_decode($data, true);

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode;

    echo json_encode($output);
    ?>
```

And then script.js - my ajax request is trying to access the data from the php file and return this into the  tag when this is clicked on:

```
$('#country-dropdown').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "php/requests.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#country-dropdown').append(`<option value="${data.features.properties.iso_a2}">${data.features.properties.name}</option>`);
            
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown + ' ' + jqXHR + ' ' + textStatus);
        }
    }); 

});
```

I'm currently receiving this error:
*SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 [object Object] parsererror*

Comment: Most likely a PHP error, warning or notice being reported. Open Developer tools in your browser (F12), click the Network tab and select your AJAX request. Then on the side choose Response to see what you actually got back.

Comment: "*My Ajax Request keeps failing*" Did you check browser's console and Network tab for any details? if it starts with `<` most probably you have a PHP error which is described with HTML, check it.

Comment: Check all the `.js` files used in the page are accessible and are not throwing any error.

Comment: Thanks all it was just that the link to my php file wasn't correct.

Comment: I am now returning the data but not sure how to access the name property with this being multi nested?